# Need 8 characters form a lengthy RegKey path - Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, registry, sccm

I have been working with a guy to finish off a rather ingenious means by which to extract information on packages installed by SCCM 2012 vs the built-in inventoried "Programs and Features".  The last piece is extracting the **PACKAGEID** from registry strings that have been inventoried in the aforementioned process.  Each string looks like this (the target "**PACKAGEID**" is identified in bold:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SMS\Mobile Client\Software Distribution\Execution History\System\ **LAB00003** \ac80c725-7dc7-11e5-9bc8-000c292d4525

As stated, i am not the genius behind any of this but i wanted to understand why i am getting the following error:

Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

From the following query:

SELECT 
   DataType0,
   KeyPath0,
   Name0,
   Value0, 
  (
      SELECT SUBSTRING(KeyPath0, LEN(LEFT(KeyPath0, CHARINDEX ('\System\', KeyPath0))) + 1, LEN(KeyPath0) - LEN(LEFT(KeyPath0, CHARINDEX ('\System\', KeyPath0))) - LEN(RIGHT(KeyPath0, LEN(KeyPath0) - CHARINDEX ('\', KeyPath0))) - 1)
   ) as "Package ID" 
FROM
  dbo.v_GS_Registry_Values0

i verified that the the *dbo.v_GS_Registry_Values0* view does indeed have the reg key string in it via select * from SCCM_Ext.vex_GS_Registry_Values0 but despite tons of searching, my simple sql mind cannot make sense of the query and its use of LEN & CHARINDEX.

Totally throwing myself at the mercy of this site in hopes i could get not only the resolution to this but also a better understanding of why this is happening and how the query works.

if there is ANY additional information i could provide please let me know.

Comment: That's because the second parameter you're passing to the outermost substring is -76 (150 - 96 - 131 - 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the next string after `\System\` you're SQL is quite complex, you can do it just with this:

```
SELECT left (Y.S, charindex ('\', Y.S) - 1)
from Table1
outer apply (
 select CHARINDEX ('\System\', KeyPath0) as pos
) X
outer apply (
 select substring (KeyPath0, X.pos + 8, 9999) as S
) Y
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/849f1/1)

The first outer apply finds the `\System\` the second gets the rest of the string (assuming max path is 9999 characters) and then just take the part before the next `\` in the actual select.

Comment: SCRATCH THAT YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!  Totally worked!  a million and one thank yous James!!!